# CLI program for xlxs -> csv conversion?

Tags: microsoft-excel, command-line, software-rec, conversion, csv

Is there an foss command line program that can convert between Excel (.XLXS) and Comma Separated Value (.CSV) files?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Use the [PowerShell Excel Module](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/7b2fdc8f-a528-4f19-b9ef-f5af349dc906). A full discussion of its features and uses is well beyond a simple Q/A, but the knowledge of its existence will get you in the right direction.

A cross-platform means of doing this without Excel being installed would be the Python tool `[xlsx2csv][2]`. The Gnumeric package can also do Excel to CSV conversions in a terminal, but it will not be cross-platform and will also require the GNOME office package to be installed.

Comment: Although @mcandre doesn't specify whether it's a requirement or not, note that this PS module will require Excel to be installed.

Comment: Any cross-platform CLI tool that doesn't require MS Office?

Comment: @mcandre: The only thing I can think of is a Java program that uses either [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org) or the [OpenDocument API](http://odftoolkit.org/projects/odfdom/pages/Home). A quick search for "java program xlsx to csv" will turn up lots of interesting results, and if you need help there's always StackOverflow. [Here's a .Net program](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246772/Convert-xlsx-xls-to-csv) too, if you need it.